# What is heavier?

Tags: physics

> **Remark:** Because of the comments I decided to drop the made up story, to remove any ambiguities.

You have a balance scale. On one side of the scale you put an $1kg$ cube made of iron, on the other side an $1kg$ cube made of balsa wood. You perform a weighing under normal conditions on earth. What will be the result of the weighing, assuming the scale is accurate enough to show any difference.

Comment: I think this question is somewhat poorly worded. The question the professor asks: "What will be the result...[of the scale measurement]" does not match with the "which weighs more" question, since a physicist would use the word *weight* slightly differently. Multiple answers seem equally valid, depending on which question you're answering.

Comment: I think the problem is that the word "weight" is inherently ambiguous (and "heavy" by association). If you explicitly define it, then it loses its puzzleness. If the question is simply "*What will be the result...*", it would be better IMO (since that seems to be the answer you actually wanted). However, it might just be a straight-up question at that point, rather than a puzzle.

Comment: Note that kilograms are a measure of mass, not of weight.  In SI units, weight is measured using newtons, since it is a force acting on an object.  So "$1kg$ is $1kg$" is correct.  While their weights (the force of gravity acting upon them) might vary, their mass will remain the same whether they are in a vacuum or not.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain Yes, that was the point of the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer:

> The iron will be heavier, because the balsa wood has more buoyancy.

To be more specific:

> The density of balsa wood is 40 - 340kg/m$^3$, and the displaced air is about 1.25kg/m$^3$, so the reduction in the balsa effective weight is between 0.4% and 3%.  The density of iron is about 8000kg/m$^3$, so the reduction is about 0.01%.

Comment: That depends on your definition of *weight*. It will register as weighing more on the scale, yes, but the definition given by [ISO/IEC 80000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_80000) excludes the effect of atmospheric buoyancy. In this case the weight is solely determined by mass and gravity.

Comment: True.  I'm assuming the OP was asking about the number that showed on his equipment, rather than an ISO standard.

Comment: I'd be more sure except for the "think like a physicist" bit. I'd expect a physicist to use the term in a "proper" way, but it could go either way :)

Comment: @Geobits The hint was there because most people are used to measure weight in kg, but it is the measurement unit for mass.

Comment: @Geobits. I could be wrong, but looking only to mass and gravity you could argue that balsa wood still is lighter because the wood has a higher center of gravity because it's volume is bigger. It will therefore experience lower gravity I think. Correct me if I'm wrong. Just thinking out loud.

Comment: You're right, but the difference would be extremely hard to detect!

Comment: 1kg of iron is a cube of 5cm on each side.  Extreme balsa wood about 30cm. Increase in centre of mass is 12.5cm.  Typing "((radius of earth +12.5cm)/(radius of earth))^2" into Google gives 1.00000002. So you'd need to detect 20micrograms on a 1kg scale.